# onBlur event prevent execution of onChange in material ui IconMenu?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, meteor-react

In my React App trying to close IconMenu using the open prop, implemented onBlur event when clicked outside of the dropdown.

Problem:- onBlur prevent the execution of the onChange event and hence unable to pick a different item from the list.

Once menu is shown and I click on the hero name, it does not change coz the only function that gets fired is closeMenu

Code

```
  let superArray=[
     {_id: 1, title: 'Spiderman' },
     {_id: 2, title: 'Captain America'},
     {_id: 4, title: 'Iron Man'}];

const HeroPicker = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    return { openMenu: false, selectedSuperId: 3 }
  },
 getHeroList() {
    return superArray.map((s, i) => {
      return (
        <MenuItem id='a1' key={i} value={s._id}>
         <span>{s && s.title}</span>
        </MenuItem>
      )
    })
  },
  onSelectHero(event, sId){
    console.log(sId);
    this.setState({ openMenu: false, selectedSuperId: sId });
  },
  showMenu() { this.setState({ openMenu: true }); },

  closeMenu() {
    console.log('this is running');
    this.setState({ openMenu: false });
  },

  render() {
    let selectedSuperId = this.state.selectedSuperId;
    let selectedSuper = superArray.find((s) => s._id == selectedSuperId);
    return (
      <div onClick={this.showMenu}>
        <IconMenu iconButtonElement={<IconButton><LocationIcon /></IconButton>}
          onChange={this.onSelectHero}
          onBlur={this.closeMenu}
          anchorOrigin={{ horizontal: 'left', vertical: 'top' }}
          targetOrigin={{ horizontal: 'left', vertical: 'top' }}
          open={this.state.openMenu}
        >
          { this.getHeroList() }
        </IconMenu>
        <span>{selectedSuper && selectedSuper.title}</span>
      </div>
    )
  }
 })
```

Can anyone guide me on this

Comment: Maybe try add a short delay to the onBlur event handler

Comment: Hey @mikeapr4 - adding delay worked, but not sure is this right way to do things